# $\langle Ax,x \rangle \geq \inf \sigma (A )$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let, $H$ be a seperable Hilbert space, $A=A^*:D(A)\subset H\rightarrow H$ be linear and bounded from below i.e. $\langle A x, x\rangle\geq c\|x\|^2$ for some constant $c$, and all $x\in H$.

Does it hold that $\langle Ax,x \rangle \geq \inf \sigma (A)$ for $x\in D(A)$ with $\|x\|=1$?

Further remarks: $A$ can be possibly unbounded. This statement appears in a part of a proof of courants minimax principle in which I'm interested in.

The statement I'm actually interested in reads:

$\langle Ax,x \rangle \geq \inf \sigma (A\vert_{P_{[s,\infty)}H})\geq s$

for some normed $x\in U$, where $U\subseteq D(A)$ is some $n$-dimensional space with $U\cap P_{[s,\infty)}H\neq \emptyset$.

$n>0$ is a fixed integer and $\Omega\mapsto P_\Omega$ is the spectral measure of $A$ (assume $H$ is seperable).
$s$ is either the $n$-th eigenvalue of $A$ counted from below respecting their multiplicity, if $s<\inf \sigma_{ess}(A)$, or $s=\inf \sigma_{ess}(A)$ if there are less then $n$ eigenvalues below $\inf \sigma_{ess}(A)$.

Note that $A\vert_{P_{\Omega}H}:P_{\Omega}H\rightarrow P_{\Omega}H $ is selfadjoint and $U\cap P_{[s,\infty)}H\neq \emptyset$ holds since $\mathrm{dim} U=n$ and $P_{(-\infty,s)}H=\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathrm{ker}(\lambda_i-A)$ and the $\lambda_i's$ are all eigenvalues below $s$, and count according to their multiplicity. Hence $\mathrm{dim}(P_{(-\infty,s)}H)<n$. Since $P_{[s,\infty)}H=(P_{(-\infty,s)}H)^\perp$, we can find a element of $U$ in it.

The second inequality $ \inf \sigma (A\vert_{P_{[s,\infty)}H})\geq s$ is clear to me. Just the first one
$\langle Ax,x \rangle \geq \inf \sigma (A\vert_{P_{[s,\infty)}H})$
bothers me.

All in one this would prove one part of courants minimax principle, thats why I'm interested in this step.

Comment: Are you assuming $M$ is invariant under $A$?  If not, what do you mean by $\sigma(A \upharpoonright M)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Hi, this is supposed to be the restriction of $A$ on $M$.

Comment: The restriction of $A$ to $M$ as an operator on $H$?  Typically the spectrum of that is all of $\mathbb C$

Comment: @RobertIsrael I'm very sorry, that was pretty unprecise formulated. I edited the question now.

Comment: Was the intent of the Question to ask about a (potentially unbounded) linear operator?   A sketch of what motivates the problem (or other context) could help present and future Readers understand what kind of information you are looking for.

Comment: @hardmath I provided more motivation on the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

This follows probably from the spectral theorem:

$\langle Ax,x\rangle=\int_{\sigma(A)}tE_x(dt)$

where $E_x\Omega:=\langle P_\Omega x,x\rangle$

Since $x$ was normed we get our estimate.

Gosh so obvious...